# DataContract Serialization (inheritance)

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, datacontract

I know there many similar question to this but still after few hours of searching I didn't find answer. I wish to serialize Child objects with fields from Person class. Here is code:

```
    [DataContract]
    abstract class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        protected int level;

        [DataMember]
        protected string name;

        public Person(int level, string name)
        {
            this.level = level;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Child))] //With and without it\\
    class Child : Person
    {
        public Child(int level, string name) : base(level , name) {}
    }
```

---

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //CREATE OBJECTS
            List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
            Person p1 = new Child(3, "ned"); p1.Display();
            Person p2 = new Child(5, "rob"); p2.Display();
            p.Add(p1); p.Add(p2);

            //SERIALIZER
            var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));

            //WRITE
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("deep.xml", FileMode.Create);
            ser.WriteObject(fs, p);
            fs.Close();

            //READ
            FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("deep.xml", FileMode.Open);
            List<Person> a = new List<Person>();
            a = (List<Person>)ser.ReadObject(fs2);
        }
    }
```

Here are my problems:

---

with the line marked as "with and without it" serialization seems to work fine but i can't deserialize it and I get "SerializationException" while doing this:

```
 a = (List<Person>)ser.ReadObject(fs2);
```

It says that error is in column 168 which is somewhere here:

```
 <Person i:type="Child">
```

---

without that line I can't even serialize. I get SerializationException and it says something about unexpected type. This error comes from this line:

```
ser.WriteObject(fs, p);
```

---

Is there something I am missing? Some explanation what exactly line "with and without it" do would be welcome. I tried to find the answer but descriptions on Microsoft site were unclear to me.

I will be very grateful for any help.

**Solution:**
Move [KnownType(typeof(Child))] to Person class. In case of multiple inheritance there can be used more than one KnowType attribute.

Link to documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As far as the serializer is concerned, the type it is serializing is `Person`.

When serializing, `Person` does not have a `DataContact` attribute, so that's the first thing to fix.

```
[DataContract]    
abstract class Person
```

The list will serialize now, but when you come to deserialize then a similar issue occurs - the deserializer only knows about the `Person` type.  The relevant part of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> The type that is instantiated for deserialization is chosen by first inspecting the incoming message to determine the data contract to which the contents of the message conform. The deserialization engine then attempts to find a CLR type that implements a data contract compatible with the message contents. The set of candidate types that the deserialization engine allows for during this process is referred to as the deserializer's set of **"known types."**

So this is where your `KnownType` attribute comes in:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Child))]
abstract class Person
```

Comment: My mistake was I didn't copy this line, there always was [DataContract] and errors still apear. But this last really helped, thanks.

Comment: Did you read the rest of my answer?  You have your `KnownType` attribute on the wrong class.

Comment: Yes I just edited reply, at first didn't see it. I wanted to correct mistake in code asap sorry. You really helped me with that thanks again. If I may only ask. This is my testing program for serialization, in original project I have more than one class that inherits from Parent. How can I make it work there?

Comment: You can add multple `KnownType` attributes - you can see this in the examples in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: I see, thanks again. It really helped me out :)
You don't even know how much time I have spent on this one.